# AFNetworking--how to pop up a loginscreen when 401 unauthorized error received?

Tags: ios, authentication, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking for my ios app.

I have made a subclass of AFHTTPClient as instructed by the docs, which will make all of my GET and POST requests.

My ViewControllers will receive any error messages as well as the payload from these requests.  How would I pop up a loginscreen as soon as my AFHTTPClient subclass receives a 401 status code?  I will need this behavior for every single request that I make, so rather than write showLoginScreen() so late in the process when the 401 bubbles up to my viewcontroller, I'd like to present the loginscreen immediately from right inside AFHTTPClient, even if I am drilled down 5 levels deep in my app.

Is this possible or a bad idea? How would I automatically pop up a loginscreen for all requests without duplicating my code in each viewController?

I want to override a method in my AFHTTPClient subclass but I don't see the correct place to do so. My initial candidate is this inside AFHTTPClient:

```
 - (void)getPath:(NSString *)path
         parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
            success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
            failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
    {
        NSURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:path parameters:parameters];
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [self HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:success failure:failure];
        [self enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
    }
```

Could anyone point out the place to insert my "showLoginScreen()" method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do following:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    // Success Response
} 
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // Check if error code is 401
    // eg [error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey] statusCode] == 401
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UnauthorizedRequest" object:nil];
}];
```

**In your AppDelegate.m**

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(showLoginView)
                                             name:@"UnauthorizedRequest"
                                           object:nil];
```

Now just implement **showLoginView** method to open the LoginView.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to have your `AFHTTPClient  subclass` post a `NSNotification` whenever a 401 occurs and have perhaps your `AppDelegate` listen and present your login screen...

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help.

Inside the AFHTTPRequestOperation class, I added a line to post an NSNotification as seen below.

```
- (void)setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
                              failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
{
    // completionBlock is manually nilled out in AFURLConnectionOperation to break the retain cycle.
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-retain-cycles"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wgnu"
    self.completionBlock = ^{
        if (self.error) {
            if (failure) {
                dispatch_async(self.failureCallbackQueue ?: dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"UnauthorizedRequest" object:nil];

                    failure(self, self.error);
                });
            }
        } else {
            if (success) {
                dispatch_async(self.successCallbackQueue ?: dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    success(self, self.responseData);
                });
            }
        }
    };
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
}
```